# Select tuneGrid depending on the model in caret R

Tags: r, r-caret

I try to apply ML on the iris dataset, using "knn" and "rpart" algorithms. This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)

dataset <- iris
tt_index <- createDataPartition(dataset$Sepal.Length, times = 1, p = 0.9, list = FALSE)
train_set <- dataset[tt_index, ]
test_set <- dataset[-tt_index, ]

models <- c("knn","rpart")

fits <- lapply(models, function(model){ 
  print(model)
  train(Species ~ ., 
        data = train_set, 
        tuneGrid = case_when(model == "knn" ~ data.frame(k = seq(3,50,1)),
                             model == "rpart" ~ data.frame(cp = seq(0,0.1,len = 50))),
        method = model)
})
```

I want to set tuneGrid parameter depending on the model inside lapply. But I receive this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(value[[1]], rep(NA_integer_, m)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `if/else`

```
library(caret)    
out <- lapply(models, function(model)
   train(Species ~ ., data = train_set, 
     tuneGrid = if(model == "knn") data.frame(k = seq(3,50,1)) else 
         data.frame(cp = seq(0,0.1,len = 50)), method = model))
```

---

According to `?case_when`

> A vector of length 1 or n, matching the length of the logical input or output vectors, with the type (and attributes) of the first RHS. Inconsistent lengths or types will generate an error.

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun, how interesting that `case_when` behaves different than ìf else`or `switch`(which I used for more models).

Comment: @Alexis it is simply beacuse it expects the type to be similar and also expects to have the same length which obviously may not be the case unless it is wrapped in a `list`